# Disable 28-day autodelete of Windows.old

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

I recently reinstalled Windows, it placed all the old stuff in a Windows.old folder.
I heard this deletes itself 28 days after installation. Is there a way to stop this?
I already renamed the folder and moved all its contents somewhere else.
Are the files still in some sort of danger? If yes, is there a way to disable this?

Comment: I don't believe the 28 days limit applied to Win 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

28 days limit applies when you upgrade [Windows 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8) into [Windows 8.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1) it will create a Windows.old folder as a backup. Reinstalling [Windows 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) will create Windows.old folder but it hasnt a limit of days to keep alive.

**Your files are safe, renaming or not cause it never will be destroyed by any proccess coz that doesnt applies to Windows 7 in none of it flavors.**

Reference [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-files-upgrade-windows-old)